# How do I change the color of an active ionic tab?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying to change the background color of an active ionic tab from white to green.  I found this thread but it seems like the answer doesn't work anymore:

https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/change-color-of-active-state-in-tab-icons/12547

Does anybody know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

add style to `.tab-item-active` class like this

```
.tab-item-active {
    background:green;
}
```

see this codepen:http://codepen.io/edisonpappi/pen/aWvmjz

Answer (score 2):

For me, setting the CSS rules for the class ".activated" worked.

```
.activated {
   background-color: blue;
}
```

This class is applied momentarily to the tab item that is selected.

Comment: I would narrow the scope to a .activated class applied on a tab element.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in the following way:

Ionic has the following css:

```
.tab-item.tab-item-active, .tab-item.active, .tab-item.activated {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

you need to override it as follows:

```
.tab-item.tab-item-active, .tab-item.active, .tab-item.activated {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the SCSS **`$tabs-ios-tab-icon-color-active`** var inside your **theme/variables.scss**, for example :

```
// App iOS Variables
// --------------------------------------------------
// iOS only Sass variables can go here

$tabs-ios-tab-icon-color: #00f;
$tabs-ios-tab-icon-color-active: #f00;


// App Material Design Variables
// --------------------------------------------------
// Material Design only Sass variables can go here

$tabs-md-tab-icon-color: #00f;
$tabs-md-tab-icon-color-active: #f00;
```

which will give you something like this :

[image: ionic-tabs-md-tab-icon-color-active-example]

For more, take a look [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/tabs/Tabs/#sass-variables).

Hope that can help.