# ionic 4 tabs how to change background color of selected tabs

Tags: tabs, background-color, ionic4

can any one help me on this:
I am already add this in 'global.scss'

```
.tab-btn-selected {
    background: rgb(134,31,194);
    color: rgb(134,31,194);
    --color-selected: rgb(134,31,194);
}

.tab-btn-selected[aria-selected=true] {
    color: #fff; /*your  text color */
    background: rgb(134,31,194); /* your background color*/
}
```

but nothing is changed.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I change the color of an active ionic tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43463223/how-do-i-change-the-color-of-an-active-ionic-tab)

Comment: Not duplicate, this is for ionic 4 in which no ".tab-item-active" class added. In this ".tab-btn-selected" class is added and having only color property.

Answer (score 7):

Just use this in your tabspage SCSS in Ionic 4,

```
ion-tab-bar{
    --color-selected: #000 !important; ( use your favourite color instead of #000 ).
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I am using ionic 4 with stenciljs.  My `<ion-tab-button/>` had the following class list when unselected:

```
class="tab-has-icon tab-has-icon-only tab-layout-icon-bottom hydrated"
```

then when selected:

```
class="tab-has-icon tab-has-icon-only tab-layout-icon-bottom hydrated tab-selected"
```

my Component had the following properties:

```
@Component({
  tag: 'app-task',
  styleUrl: 'app-task.css'
})
```

so I added the following to app-task.css and was able to change the font and background color:

```
.tab-selected{
  background: rgb(134,31,194) !important;
  color: white !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this answer helped me change the icon and text colors. I put <.tab-selected> in the tabs.page.scss and works fine in Ionic 4. I changed only the icon and text colors with this code: 

.tab-selected{
    ion-icon{
        color: #dd3d3d;
    }
    ion-label{
        color: #dd3d3d;
    }
  }

Answer (score 2):

In ionic 4 with angular 8 I got it work in web browsers like this (not tested on mobile devices):

in global.css I added:

```
ion-tab-button {
  --ripple-color: var(--ion-color-medium);
  --color: var(--ion-color-dark);
  --color-selected: var(--ion-color-medium);
}

ion-tab-button.tab-selected {
  --background: var(--ion-color-dark) !important;
  --color-selected: var(--ion-color-light);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I did it on *variables.scss*:

```
--ion-tabbar-text-color-active: rgb(134,31,194);
```

Comment: @user2734974 :root { }

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<ion-tabs>

  <ion-tab-bar slot="bottom">
    <ion-tab-button tab="index">
      <ion-icon name="list"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Lessons</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

    <ion-tab-button class="favorites-button" tab="favorites">
      <ion-icon name="heart"></ion-icon>
      <ion-label>Favorites</ion-label>
    </ion-tab-button>

  </ion-tab-bar>

</ion-tabs>
```

SCSS

```
ion-tab-button.favorites-button {
    --color-selected: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me

```
ion-tab-button[aria-selected=true] {
    background-color: #ddd;
 }
```